# Checking if line in file exists

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, profile

I have a bash script which asks a user for the number of CPU cores and saves it to variable named `$cores`.
Now I want to add this variable to `.bashrc`, so I ask user how many CPU cores he has and then if he wants to save this value to `.bashrc`.

Now the question: how can I check if `$cores` already exists in `.bashrc` so the script won't ask the user again?

Comment: Note that the `.bashrc` belongs to the user and may be shared by different machines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can check whether a variable is set in bash using:

```
if [[ -z "$cores" ]]
then
    echo "not set"
else
    echo "set"
fi
```

This will check whether `$cores` variable is set or not. that is if $cores is null it will display "not set" otherwise "set". As a matter of fact `.bashrc` is not sourced automatically for non-interactive shells, such as those started when you execute a shell script. So you would put `. .bashrc` near the beginning of your `.bash_login` file, to ensure that `.bashrc` is sourced for both login and non-login interactive shells.

Comment: That checks if the variable is empty. That condition is true for unset variables but also for variables that are set to the empty string. `[[ -z "${cores+set}" ]]` would be for checking specifically if the variable is _unset_ (that also works for array or hash variables with `bash` or `zsh`, but not `ksh93` (though with `bash` if an array or hash is set but has no member, it's considered unset (a WA is to use `declare -p array > /dev/null 2>&1`))).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of prompting the user for how many cores the system has, why not just ask the system?  This is better because it doesn't involve writing to a user-owned file.  See something like [this](https://gist.github.com/jj1bdx/5746298), which uses 'getconf' to request NPROCESSORS_CONF variable.  Or for other systems, the ideas presented [here](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2012-11/msg00004.html) may be helpful - using `sysctl` or a grep over `/proc/cpuinfo` to find the number of cores.

Comment: It basically needs number of "make -jX" to use. Usually CPU Core number is used, but somebody may use something else.

Comment: See also `info libc 'Processor Resources'` on a GNU system for more details. Using NPROCESSORS_ONLN (the number of _online_ processors), would be better than NPROCESSORS_CONF (the number of processors _present_).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'awk /\$core/ { print }'
```

Comment: The `{print}` is redundant in this case (it is `awk`'s default)...