# How do I check if a variable exists in an 'if' statement?

Tags: bash, variable, test

I need to check a variable's existence in an `if` statement. Something to the effect of:

```
if [ -v $somevar ]
then
    echo "Variable somevar exists!"
else
    echo "Variable somevar does not exist!"
```

And the closest question to that was [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/checking-if-line-in-file-exist/), which doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: If you want to set `$somevar` to a value/string if variable does not exist: `${somevar:=42}`.

Comment: Personally, I tend to check  just for emptiness (`[ -n "$var" ]` or `[ ! -z "$var" ]`). I think the existence/nonexistence checks are too subtle, and I prefer my code coarse and simple.

Comment: Why do you need that vs `[ -n "$var" ]`? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Answer (score 153, accepted):

In modern bash (version 4.2 and above):

```
[[ -v name_of_var ]]
```

From `help test`:

> -v VAR, True if the shell variable VAR is set

Comment: Also works with single brackets: `[ -v name_of_var ]`.

Comment: beware that for hashes and arrays, it returns false unless the variable has an element of key/indice "0". For namerefs, it tests whether the target is defined. It doesn't work for special parameters like `$1`, `$-`, `$#`...

Comment: This feature is only in the bash builtin `test` or `[` ; It is not available in `/usr/bin/test`. Compare `man test` with `help test`.

Comment: @MarkLakata Right, because external commands cannot know the internal state of the shell.

Comment: umm shouldn't it always be [[ -v "$name_of_var" ]] ?

Comment: @AlexanderMills No. That would if the variable name in `$name_of_var` existed. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Also works in zsh from version 5.3+

Comment: Not sure why it's an accepted answer. OP did not limit shell to bash only.

Comment: It throws `unbound variable` if script has `set -u`

Comment: @Ragtime It doesn't. Try `bash -u -c '[[ -v nowarn ]]; echo "$warn"'` -- only "$warn" will print "unbound variable".

Answer (score 46):

Depends what you mean by *exists*.

Does a variable that has been declared but not assigned *exist*?

Does an array (or hash) variable that has been assigned an empty list *exist*?

Does a nameref variable pointing to a variable that currently isn't assigned *exist*?

Do you consider `$-`, `$#`, `$1` variables? (POSIX doesn't).

In Bourne-like shells, the canonical way is:

```
if [ -n "${var+set}" ]; then
  echo '$var was set'
fi
```

That works for scalar variables and other parameters to tell if a variable has been assigned a value (empty or not, automatically, from the environment, assigments, `read`, `for` or other).

For shells that have a `typeset` or `declare` command, that would not report as *set* the variables that have been *declared* but not *assigned* (note that in `zsh`, declaring a variable assigns a value, a default one if not specified).

For shells that support arrays, except for `yash` and `zsh` that would not report as *set* array variables unless the element of indice 0 has been set.

For `bash` (but not `ksh93` nor `zsh`), for variables of type *associative array*, that would not report them as *set* unless their element of key "0" has been set.

For `ksh93` and `bash`, for variables of type *nameref*, that only returns true if the variable referenced by the nameref is itself considered *set*.

For `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, a potentially better approach could be:

```
if ((${#var[@]})); then
  echo '$var (or the variable it references for namerefs) or any of its elements for array/hashes has been set'
fi
```

For `ksh93`, `zsh` and `bash` 4.4 or above, there's also:

```
if typeset -p var 2> /dev/null | grep -q '^'; then
  echo '$var exists'
fi
```

Which will report variables that have been set or declared.

Comment: `declare -p` / `typeset -p` works in `bash` now too.

Comment: @cas, no. Not for declared but not set variables. Try `bash -c 'typeset -i a; typeset -p a'` and compare with `ksh93` or `zsh`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for point me here. Also see my question http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280893/674

Comment: @cas, that changed with bash-4.4 (released in September 2016), I've edited that in.

Comment: Don't check the length (the `-n` flag for `test`) in POSIX. Simply do `[ "${var+.}" ]`. The plus expansion substitutes [unset to null string](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and test evaluates [true if *string* is not the null string](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05), thus the entire expression evaluates to false only when `$var` is unset.

Comment: @antichris, that's a matter of taste. I do prefer the `[ -n string ]` over `[ string ]` as it makes it clearer what is being tested as it follows the usual `[ -operator operand ]` pattern.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, you are mistaken. It is a matter of performance. Most of POSIX compliant implementations (`zsh` being an exception), return something along the lines of `argv[pos][0] != '\0'` *immediately* when a single argument expression is parsed. When the first argument of two starts with a `-` (as would be the case with `-n`) they descend into a more or less gnarly unary operator resolution. I really don't see any added value in typing longer expressions that evaluate (marginally, true, but still) slower, but have the *exact* same result (in this case).

Comment: @antichris, that's hardly relevant, in both cases it's a builtin call. You might save 10% of a few hundred nanosecond calls with some implementation when a shell's job is to run commands which take at least a few miliseconds to run. I don't want to be drawn into this kind of micro-optimisations when that diminishes legibility. `[ -z ]`, `[ -n ]` come together for null and non-null string tests. I'm not going to replace `[ -z "$var" ]` with `[ ! "$var" ]` or `[ "$#" -ne 0 ]` with `[ "${1+x}" ]`, we'll have to agree to disagree on our priorities.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `[ "${var+.}" ]` is shorter, sweeter *and* faster (and those factors become significant, for example, when dropping a shellcode). Just saying. But you do you.

Comment: @antichris no it isn't for that vast majority. It's shorter and sweeter for experts that revel in such things, I do. But its not at all legible to anyone trying to understand a script when they are not experts. -n is easily googled and checked. Nobody cares about micro optimisations in a script that might be called once per session and, in any case, you could argue the compiler/interpreter would optimise it anyway.

Comment: @RichieHH you almost got it, it's just the other way around. When I first saw the `[ -n "$var" ]` idiom in a script, I did indeed have to look it up (google or `man`), because a flag like that could mean practically anything (especially to a non-expert, inexperienced first-timer, as I was back then), while the meaning of `[ "$var" ]` and `[ ! "$var"]` has always seemed perfectly obvious to me, right from the very beginning. It's precisely the `-n` and `-z` flags that I still have to look up every once in a while to verify that I'm not mistaking one for the other.

Comment: @antichris, and do you find it obvious that `[ 0 ]` or `[ ! ]` should return true? Why should `[ x ]` check for that very property that `x` be non-empty as opposed to any other property/test one could  have chosen instead (is a non-zero number, is a readable file, is a know test operator...). Note that `[ -t ]` in some shells/tests returns true if stdin is a terminal. `[[ $var ]]` used not to be supported in zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sure. The `test` command takes parameters, they have semantics and are *very* well documented. As for the non-emptiness check, in my experience, all languages that accept a single variable as a boolean expression have converged upon checking the "truthiness" of its value. Since POSIX shell variables can only contain (null-terminated) string values, it seems self-evident that a non-empty one *must* be truthy. POSIX spec has the FD number for a `-t` test mandatory, what you're describing is non-compliant. Double-brackets and zsh are non-POSIX so, frankly, IDGAF about either.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in the answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash), here is a way to check:

```
if [ -z ${somevar+x} ]; then echo "somevar is unset"; else echo "somevar is set to '$somevar'"; fi
```

where ${somevar+x} is a parameter expansion which evaluates to the null if var is unset and substitutes the string "x" otherwise.

Using `-n`, as suggested by the other answer, will only check if the variable contains empty string. It will not check its existence.

Comment: You need to quote `$somevar` to handle `IFS=x`. Either that or quote `x`.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks, I like learning about edge cases :) Do you mean `if [ -z "${somevar+x}" ]`?  Would the quoting still be required inside `[[` and `]]`?

Comment: @TomHale   - yes, in rare cases. the `[ test` routines accept command line parameters, and so the usual expansions and interpretations as ordered in the usual way should be relied upon to render at invocation of the test applied that which you should cause to be read thereby by any program command line. test{!+"!"}

Comment: @mikeserv I guess your yes is to my 2nd question... Is the first a yes, too?

Comment: @Tom Hale - to my my way of thinking, `[ -z`, if applied at all to a parameter check, is most useful as a corner case standin. the not applicable corollary... `[ ${*?cant handle that, bash? or do the prior bournes slip at :? theres a test for that, too, if your word is worth the encoding... save for later? freezers are cool}` and plus works for almost anything (*stay positive, everybody*) `[ ${-+"-z"} $- ]&& now what?` of course, by design, file system glo[bal]{1,2}ing might not be so confusing as a possible forty-two deep link back check... fortuitous? thats quite a lot.

Comment: Sorry @mikeserv, I have no idea what you mean... would you mind to try again with more simple examples?

Comment: +1; this appears to be the simplest way to do this when `set -u` is in effect and the Bash version is pre-4.2.

Comment: @KyleStrand I usually do that with [[ -n ${MY_VAR:-} ]]

Comment: @Jupiter Yeah, that should be equivalent, I think, though it may need quotes around the expansion.

Answer (score 6):

POSIXly:

```
! (: "${somevar?}") 2>/dev/null && echo somevar unset
```

or you can let your shell show the message for you:

```
(: "${somevar?}")
zsh: somevar: parameter not set
```

Comment: @mikeserv: Yeah, of course, there's many way to do it. Firstly, I think I will duplicated it with [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208185/38906). But in this question, the OP want to check only, he didn't claim that he want to exit or report if variable unset, so I came with a check in subshell.

Comment: Well, i know, but it's precisely because you have to do it in a subshell like that which indicates it might not be the best way to test here - that's a halt action on failure, it doesn't allow for any simple means to handle a failure. Portably even a `trap` can only work on EXIT. That's all I'm saying - it just doesn't apply as a pass/fail very well. And this isn't me talking either - i've done exactly this before and it took a little comment chat just like this to convince me. So, I just thought I'd pay it forward.

Comment: @mikeserv: Well, well, it's a good point. I only wonder, does adding that can make the OP confuse with the syntax :)

Comment: you might want to "peel the onion" a bit here to unpack that command for the OP or other bash learners. It's definitely packing a lot of concepts, aside from the fact that it doesn't feature the "if statement" that the OP asked about.

Answer (score 3):

```
if set|grep '^somevar=' >/dev/null;then
    echo "somevar exists"
else
    echo "does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: I would imagine this to be somewhat inefficient, but it is very simple and `sh` compatible, which is just what I need.

Answer (score 3):

This simple line works (and works on most POSIX shells):

```sh
${var+"false"} && echo "var is unset"
```

Or, written in a longer form:

```sh
unset var

if ${var+"false"}
then
   echo "var is unset"
fi
```

The expansion is:

- If the var has a value (even null), false is replaced
- If the var has "no value", then "no value" (null) is replaced.

The `${var+"false"}` expansion expands to either "null" of "false".
Then, "nothing" or the "false" is executed, and the exit code set.

There is no need to call the command `test` (`[` or `[[`) as the exit value is set by the (execution of) the expansion itself.

Comment: Yes, except in some old versions of zsh in sh emulation when `$IFS` contains f, a, l, s or e. Like for other answers, there's the case of arrays, hashes, or other types of variables which one may want to mention.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I wrote `most POSIX shells`. `most` [means `In the greatest number of instances`](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/most), not all. ... ... So, yes, in an obscure condition `when $IFS contains f, a, l, s or e` and for some obscure shell `some old versions of zsh` this fails: What a shock!. I should assume that such bug has been solved long ago. ... ... Are you proposing that we must write code for long ago broken shells?.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Also: The question title is very specific: Bash.

Comment: binary zebra???

Answer (score 2):

```
printf ${var+'$var exists!\n'}
```

...will print nothing at all when it doesn't. Or...

```
printf $"var does%${var+.}s exist%c\n" \ not !
```

...will tell you either way.

you can use the return value of a test to dynamically expand to the appropriate format string for your condition:

```
[ "${var+1}" ]
printf $"var does%.$?0s exist%c\n" \ not !
```

You can also make `printf` fail based on a substitution...

```
printf $"var does%${var+.}s exist%c\n%.${var+b}d" \
        \ not ! \\c >&"$((2${var+-1}))" 2>/dev/null
```

...which prints *`$var does not exist!`* to stderr and returns other than 0 when `$var` is unset, but prints *`$var does exist!`* to stdout and returns 0 when `$var` is set.

Answer (score 2):

The pure shell way:

```
[ "${var+1}" ] || echo "The variable has not been set"
```

Test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Test 1, var has not yet been created"
[ "${var+1}" ] || echo "The variable has not been set"

echo "Test 2, var=1"
var=1
[ "${var+1}" ] || echo "The variable has not been set"

echo "Test 3, var="
var=
[ "${var+1}" ] || echo "The variable has not been set"

echo "Test 4, unset var"
unset var
[ "${var+1}" ] || echo "The variable has not been set"
echo "Done"
```

Results:

```
Test 1, var has not yet been created
The variable has not been set
Test 2, var=1
Test 3, var=
Test 4, unset var
The variable has not been set
Done
```

Comment: Fails when variable set to null string.

Comment: +1 This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

With bash 4.4.19 the following worked for me. Here is a complete example

```
$export MAGENTO_DB_HOST="anyvalue"

#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$MAGENTO_DB_HOST" ]; then
    echo "Magento variable not set"
else
    echo $MAGENTO_DB_HOST
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

**bash** function that works for both **scalar** and **array** types:

#### definition

```
has_declare() { # check if variable is set at all
    local "$@" # inject 'name' argument in local scope
    &>/dev/null declare -p "$name" # return 0 when var is present
}
```

#### invocation

```
if has_declare name="vars_name" ; then
   echo "variable present: vars_name=$vars_name"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `if` command to check the existence of declared variables in bash however `-v` option exists in newer bash, but it's not portable and you can't use it in older `bash` versions. Because when you are using a variable if it doesn't exists it will born at the same time.

E.g. Imagine that I didn't use or assign a value to the `MYTEST` variable, but when you are using echo command it shows you nothing! Or if you are using `if [ -z $MYTEST ]` it returned zero value!
It didn't return another exit status, which tells you that this variable doesn't exist!

Now you have two solutions (Without `-v` option):

2. Using `declare` command.
3. Using `set` command.

For example:

```
MYTEST=2
set | grep MYTEST
declare | grep MYTEST
```

But unfortunately these commands shows you loaded functions in memory too! You can use `declare -p | grep -q MYTEST ; echo $?` command for cleaner result.

Answer (score 0):

## Function to check if variable is declared/unset

### including empty `$array=()`

In addition to @Gilles's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56846/158123)

> ```
> case " ${!foobar*} " in
>   *" foobar "*) echo "foobar is declared";;
>   *) echo "foobar is not declared";;
> esac
> ```

-- which I did not find a way for to encapsulate it within a function -- I'd like to add a simple version, which is partly based on [Richard Hansen](https://serverfault.com/users/84843/richard-hansen)'s [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382740/204530), but does address also the pitfall that occurs with an empty `array=()`:

```
# The first parameter needs to be the name of the variable to be checked.
# (See example below)

var_is_declared() {
    { [[ -n ${!1+anything} ]] || declare -p $1 &>/dev/null;}
}

var_is_unset() {
    { [[ -z ${!1+anything} ]] && ! declare -p $1 &>/dev/null;} 
}
```

- By first testing if the variable is (un)set, the call to declare can be avoided, if not necessary.
- If however `$1` contains the name of an empty `$array=()`, the call to declare would make sure we get the right result
- There's never much data passed to /dev/null as declare is only called if either the variable is unset or an empty array.

With the following code the functions can be tested:

```
( # start a subshell to encapsulate functions/vars for easy copy-paste into the terminal
  # do not use this extra parenthesis () in a script!

var_is_declared() {
    { [[ -n ${!1+anything} ]] || declare -p $1 &>/dev/null;}
}

var_is_unset() {
    { [[ -z ${!1+anything} ]] && ! declare -p $1 &>/dev/null;} 
}

:;       echo -n 'a;       '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
a=;      echo -n 'a=;      '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
a="sd";  echo -n 'a="sd";  '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
a=();    echo -n 'a=();    '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
a=("");  echo -n 'a=("");  '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
unset a; echo -n 'unset a; '; var_is_declared a && echo "# is declared" || echo "# is not declared"
echo ;
:;       echo -n 'a;       '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
a=;      echo -n 'a=;      '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
a="foo"; echo -n 'a="foo"; '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
a=();    echo -n 'a=();    '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
a=("");  echo -n 'a=("");  '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
unset a; echo -n 'unset a; '; var_is_unset a && echo "# is unset" || echo "# is not unset"
)
```

The script should return

```
a;       # is not declared
a=;      # is declared
a="foo"; # is declared
a=();    # is declared
a=("");  # is declared
unset a; # is not declared

a;       # is unset
a=;      # is not unset
a="foo"; # is not unset
a=();    # is not unset
a=("");  # is not unset
unset a; # is unset
```