# How do I check whether a variable has been passed to a function in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this:

```
function abash {
    if [[ -v $1 ]]
        then
            atom ~/Shell/$1.sh
        else
            atom ~/.bashrc
    fi
}
```

in my `~/.bashrc` file, so as to make it easier to use Atom to edit my bash scripts, now the problem is that `[[ -v $1 ]]` is meant to be checking whether the input `$1` exists but it does not appear to be, as even when I provide a valid input (e.g., running `abash cd` where `~/Shell/cd.sh` is a file I want to edit) abash opens up `~/.bashrc`. How do I fix this problem? Where did I get the idea for the `[[ -v $1]]` test? [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212192/27613) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` conditional expression `-v var` check if *shell variable* named `var` is set.

When using `[[ -v $1 ]]`, you actually checked whether a variable named by content of `$1` was set. In your example, it means `$cd`, which was never set.

You can simply check if `$1` is non-empty string, using `-n`:

```
function abash {
    if [[ -n "$1" ]]
        then
            atom ~/Shell/"$1.sh"
        else
            atom ~/.bashrc
    fi
}
```

---

Note that `var` must be a *shell variable* for `-v var` work. `[[ -v 1 ]]` will never work because `1` is denoted for *positional parameter*.

Comment: Still isn't working I'm afraid. It still keeps opening up `~/.bashrc` when I run `abash cd`. If you're wondering whether I'm forgetting to source (`source ~/.bashrc`) it, don't, as I've got another function `sbash` that does that for me and I keep running it whenever I make changes to my bash scripts.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: What's `sbash` look like? how did you run it?

Comment: Even with the quotation marks (`""`) around `$1.sh` I'm afraid `abash cd` still keeps opening up `~/.bashrc`

Comment: [sbash](http://pastebin.com/rqD0buDR). I run `sbash && abash cd` to test whether your solution or Sparhawk's are valid from LXTerminal.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: The quote is for safe and not related to the logic in if condition. We can't help if you don't provide more information, what `sbash` look like and how did you run it?

Comment: Surely `if [ "$1" ]` is all that is needed for the conditional.  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @BrentonHorne: So what happen when you open new bash session?

Comment: Oops, nvm, turns out that I was using a new conditional in my ~/.bashrc script to execute all files in ~/Shell, including ~/Shell/bash.sh which is where I share abash and it was screwing up. Opening a new tab is what taught me that.

Comment: @cuonglm, `[ -n $1 ]` will fail with error if $1 happens to be an empty string.  quotes are required here.  `[ -n "$1" ]`

Comment: @cas: You don't need quote in new test `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: `$ [[ -n  ]] && echo foo
bash: unexpected argument \`]]' to conditional unary operator
bash: syntax error near \`]]'
`

Comment: @cas: your test is invalid. Try `a=; [[ -n $a ]]`

Comment: ah, that's right.  but it doesn't matter.  **always** quote variables unless you are deliberately relying on auto-splitting by $IFS.  even when it's not a syntax error, it's a bug waiting to happen.  e.g. try passing a single arg like `'two or more words'` or `'filename with a space in it'` to that function.

Comment: @cas: Yes, I *definitely* know it. Read the man `bash` and find the section about new test `[[ ... ]]`. No globbing or splitting perform inside new test.

Comment: @cas: If you talk about standard, then it doesn't matter. But in case of non-standard specific feature, it does. Using double quote inside new test can lead to different behavior with some operator like `==` or `=~`.

Comment: I'm not talking about standards.  I'm talking about the practicalities of people coming here, seeing examples that don't bother to quote variables in the small handful of cases where it's not needed, copy-paste it into a situation where quotes are needed, and then wonder why it doesn't work.  Example code here is seen by a lot more than just the OP, so it should be written so as to be safe when copied and modified.

Comment: @cas: I don't see you address that problem at the first place, and also we want people to learn instead of copy-paste machine. If that's your goal, then you must go through all zsh example and double quote those variables, mustn't you? Anyway, I'm going to add it.

Comment: it's not my job to fix all the broken examples here.  i commented now because i saw someone who is skilled enough to know better providing a bad example.  btw, newbies learn partly by copy-paste-editing, copying what works for other people and trying to adapt it to their needs.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why this fails, but there are (at least) two other possible options. Instead of `[[ -v $1 ]]`, you could use either of the following.

Check that the number of arguments is more than zero.

```
[[ $# > 0 ]]
```

Check that the first argument is not empty.

```
[[ $1 != '' ]]
```

Comment: It's quite unpleasant that UL treats the `#` here as command start.

Comment: My apologies, I just tested your answer and it is equally valid as cuonglm's, if I could accept both of your answers I would.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 Fixed! :D

Comment: @BrentonHorne No worries! cuonglm explained why it failed, so on that basis it's a better answer anyway. And he beat me by 5 minutes. ;)

Comment: Couldn't you use `[ $# > 0 ]` just as well and have it portable?

Comment: @Wildcard I was just making minimal modifications to the original question, but yes, portability might be a good idea. The syntax changes slightly for `[`; you'd have to use `[ $# -gt 0 ]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be in the test is the **name** of the var, a tag name, if you wish. To test the variable a, you do **not** do `[[ -v $a ]], you do:

```
[[ -v a ]]
```

However, there is no way (AFAIK) to test positional parameters with `-v` because, in essence, positional parameters have no name. Or, if you wish, they are numbers, and the test does not work with a number.

So, you need to test the var directly without the help of `-v` as this:

```
[[ ${1:+present} ]]
```

---

Also:

You should quote your var expansions.
I prefer to use $HOME, instead of the tilde. It allows quoted strings.

```
abash() {
    if [[ ${1:+present} ]]
        then
            atom "$HOME/Shell/$1.sh"
        else
            atom "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
}
```

The answer is [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13365252/2350426) but please take note of the `:` that I included to make it work correctly.