# What is the definition of an array being set?

Tags: bash

1. The definition for an array being set is from bash manual:

   > An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value. The null string is a valid value.

   - Does it mean that an array is set if and only if the number of its elements is
     greater than zero?
   - Is the following array set, `myarr=()`?
   - The manual also says

     > A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value. The null string is a valid value.

     Since an array is also a parameter, how does the definition of an array being set agree with the definition of a parameter being set?

     For example, `myvar=""` is set, but is `myarr=()` set? Has `myarr` been assigned a value, which is null?
2. There is a different definition for an array being set from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246703/674

   > For shells that support arrays, except for yash and zsh that would not report as set array variables unless the element of indice 0 has
   >   been set.
   >
   > For bash (but not ksh93 nor zsh), for variables of type associative array, that would not report them as set unless their
   >   element of key "0" has been set.

   Is this definition incorrect, because an array name without
   subscription actually refers to the element indexed by index/key `0`
   instead of referring to the entire array, according to Bash manual

   > Referencing an
   >   array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0.

   So is this definition
   actually for the element indexed by index/key `0` being set, not for the array being set?

   For example, `${myarr+1}` and `[[ -v myarr ]]` are the applications  to an array `myarr` the usual ways of testing if a variable/parameter is set. Which does `myarr` in  them mean: `myarr[0]`, or the entire array `myarr`?
3. What is POSIX definition for a shell array being set?

Comment: You can try yourself: `set -u; x=([1]=b); echo $x` or `set -u; declare -A x; x=([a]=b); echo $x`, then try the same with 0 instead of 1 and `a` respectively.

Comment: @choroba: Thanks. Does `x` in `echo $x` mean `x[0]` or the array? Does your example test which one is set, `x[0]` or the array?

Comment: Why do you need to know whether an array is set?

Comment: Why do you not need to

Comment: You answered your own question in the first line: *"What is the definition of an array being set?"* *"The definition for an array being set is from bash manual:
An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value. The null string is a valid value."*  At the very least you need to fix the question title, or this will be closed as unclear what you're asking (my prediction).

Comment: @Tim: If we knew why you needed it, we could recommend an alternative solution.

Comment: Because simply I want to know the concept. @choroba

Comment: POSIX sh doesn't have arrays.

Comment: Why do you think an array is also a parameter?

Comment: because I read the bash manual, and you don't: "Bash provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables. Any variable may
be used as an indexed array; the declare builtin will explicitly declare an array."

Answer (score 0):

> - Does it mean that an array is set if and only if the number of its elements is greater than zero?

Yes.

> - Is the following array set, myarr=()?

No.

> - how does the definition of an array being set agree with the definition of a parameter being set?

Both are meant to be equal, I see no problem here:

- A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value. The null string is a valid value.
- An array variable is considered set if ... has been assigned a value. The null string is a valid value.

---

> 2. There is a different definition ...

What the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246703/674 is describing is the details of how the test `[ -n "${var+set}" ]` work, not defining what is set or not, not for normal variables, not for arrays.

Please note the `that` in `that would not report ...`.

---

> 3. What is POSIX definition for a shell array being set?

There are no "shell arrays" in POSIX.