# Bash: while loop over numbered variables

Tags: bash, variable

My environment can have a flexible number of variables defined with the following format:

```
Var1Value=A
Var2Value=B
Var3Value=C
```

I now would like to iterate over the variables as long as they exists. 
In pseudo code:

```
i=1
while [exists "Var"$i"Value"]; do
 echo "found variable, now doing some more complex processing logic"
 #do some more stuff
 i=$((i + 1)) 
done
```

I do I make this work in bash (without using arrays)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a variable exists in an 'if' statement?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/212183)

Answer (score 5):

Use a [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html). They work sort of like pointers to other variables (in Bash 4.3 and later):

```
Var1Value=A
Var2Value=B
Var3Value=C
Var4Value=""

for (( i=1 ; ; i++ )); do
    n="Var${i}Value"                # the name of var
    declare -n p="$n"               # reference to the var
    [ "${p+x}" ] || break           # see if it exists
    echo "$n: '$p'"
done
```

`"${p+x}"` evaluates to `x` if the variable pointed to by `p` exists, so this deals with set but empty variables, too.

Alternatively, use indirect variable expansion `${!n}`, which refers to the variable named by `n`.

```
for (( i=1 ; ; i++ )); do
    n="Var${i}Value"                # the name of var
    [ "${!n+x}" ] || break          # see if it exists
    echo "$n: '${!n}'"
done
```

But really, you should use an array. None of the three choices here are standard, but arrays are by far the most logical.

```
VarValue=( A B C )

for value in "${VarValue[@]}"; do
    # use "$value" here
    printf 'Value is "%s"\n' "$value"
done
```

See also:

- BashFAQ 006: [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    eval echo "$"$(eval echo Var${i}Value)
done
```

There's a joke in there somewhere about it being horribly `eval`...

Comment: I suspect I probably don't really need the inner `eval`, but I'm not interested in optimizing this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rich. The echo statement is meant as a placeholder for some more complicated work, therefore I'd still need a conditional statement which is what I'm struggling with. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable is set, see [How do I check if a variable exists in an 'if' statement?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212183) (`[ -v "Var${i}Value" ]` (`ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`) or `eval "[ -n \"\${Var${i}Value+set}\" ]"` (POSIX)).

Now, to loop over the variables whose name matches a pattern, in `zsh`, you could do:

```
for varname in ${(Mk)parameters:#Var<->Value}; do
  something with "$varname" and its value: "${(P)varname}"
done
```

To process them in numeric order, add the `n` parameter expansion flag (change `Mk` to `Mkn`).

With `bash`:

```
readarray -t list < <(compgen -v | grep -xE 'Var[[:digit:]]+Value')
for varname in "${list[@]}"; do
  something with "$varname" and its value: "${!varname}"
done
```

Or replacing the `readarray` with split+glob to avoid using an array:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline
for varname in $(compgen -v | grep -xE 'Var[[:digit:]]+Value'); do
  something with "$varname" and its value: "${!varname}"
done
```

To process them in numeric order and assuming your `sort` is GNU  `sort`, pipe the output of `grep` into `sort -V`.

Comment: Question explicitly states "without using arrays", and your bash solution makes an array.

Comment: @Rich, I interpret the _without using arrays_ as meaning without replacing the `varxvalue` with `varvalue[x]`. I've added a split+glob variant that avoids the _array_ variable.

Comment: And that would be a highly accurate description of exactly what you're doing in your solution - aside from the fact you also changed the name from `varvalue[x]` to `list[x]`.

Comment: @Rich, no list holds the list of variable names, so we can loop over them later, not their values.

Comment: I see you added a split+glob solution to your answer. Thank you for recognizing your error in working to the specification!

Answer (score 0):

For loop can be used if variables are known:

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in var1 var2 var3
        do
           echo " This is $i"
           #More commands.
        done
```

**output**

```
 This is var1
 This is var2
 This is var3
```