# zsh -z test meaning of "+x"

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I am new to zsh and have been a bash user for years.

In an example zsh script I see a test:

`if [ ! -z ${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x} ]; then`

In bash I would expect:

`if [ ! -z "$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM" ]; then`

I don't understand the meaning of +x in the zsh example and if is applicable to bash.

Comment: The second line should work for `zsh` as well. You can shorten it (in `bash` and `zsh`) to `if [ -n "$VAR" ]; then`. I haven't seen the first line yet.

Comment: Related: [How do I check if a variable exists in an 'if' statement?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212183/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: @pfnuesel, it works, as in does something and doesn't give errors, yes. It just doesn't do the same thing as the first one. Namely there's the case of a variable set to the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parameter (variable) expansion syntax that's also found in Bash.  Probably in most other Bourne-style shells, too.  The only thing special to zsh in your example is the variable being tested.

In the bash man page we see two things.  The explanation of this expansion syntax:

```
  ${parameter:+word}
    Use Alternate Value. If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted,
    otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
```

And a few paragraphs earlier, at the top of the section of expansion syntax, there is something a lot of people overlook:

```
  When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below
  (e.g., :-),  bash  tests for a parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting
  the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.
```

That last sentence is the relevant part: `Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.`  To illustrate, the syntax as given in the man page is:

```
  ${parameter:+word}
```

with the colon omitted it is:

```
  ${parameter+word}
```

And the difference is that the latter syntax returns the value in **word** in all cases except when the variable is unset (doesn't exist).  So the syntax you saw in your zsh script:

```
  ${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}
```

Returns `x` if `$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM` has been defined (no matter what the value is - even an empty string), but returns an empty string if the variable is not defined.

In the end, your script example tests only that the variable exists, without regard to the value it contains.  I answered by quoting the Bash man page because you mentioned you have been a bash user and will find the bash descriptions familiar.

It's not a common idiom in the Bourne-style shell scripts I've seen over my (fairly long) career, so a lot of people aren't aware of the `:-`, `:=`, `:?`, and `:+` syntax without the `:`.  I learned about them only recently myself.

Comment: "the latter syntax returns the value in word only when the variable is unset (doesn't exist)." -- pretty much the opposite actually, doesn't it?

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with the quotes (not even the part you formatted as code even though it clearly isn't. If you wanted to highlight it, why not use _italics_ or **bold**?) It has to do with what `+` does. Try it: `unset foo; echo "${foo+x}"` vs. the same with `foo=`, or `foo=abc`, or with `"${foo-x}"` instead.

Comment: anyway, I would also suggest using quote formatting instead of code blocks when quoting man pages, mostly because having word wrapping helps when the reader's screen isn't wide enough that the whole text fits. It's not like documentation text is that sensitive to having the linebreaks at the exact places.

Comment: @ikkachu thanks for the suggestion regarding formatting, but I considered it more important in these excerpts from man pages that they look more like man page output - with similar monospace font and indentation.  I don't believe anyone will see those particular excerpts and mistakenly believe they're code.

Comment: Did you test any of that? Where did I get the idea that `${parameter+word}` returns `word` when the parameter is set? Humor me, try `foo=123; echo "${foo+x}"` and tell me what it prints? What shell are you running?

Comment: Did you read the parts you quoted from the man page? Did you notice how the first one has `${parameter:+word}` and mentions it substitutes the expansion of "word" if the parameter is set and not null, and how the second one refers to `:-` instead? What the `+` and `-` do are listed in the man page...

Comment: Note that there's also the online reference manual, with the same content but without the monospace formatting: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html (except for the parts that are actually code, and it also makes the `:-` within the text at least a bit more visibly marked)

Comment: As an aside, I think this area is one where the Bash manual is a bit too confusingly written, mostly about how it almost ignores the colon-less variants. On the other hand, the POSIX text has a nice table of the combinations: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes there are dozens if not hundreds of Q&A's here which are mostly a consequence of the documentation for `${var-x}`/`${var+x}`/`${var=x}` being hard to find in the bash manual.

Comment: @ikkachu I tested and saw my error describing how the expansion works.  Fixed that error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`${var+string}` is the same operator as in the Bourne shell (from the late 70s) and in any POSIX shell (including bash). You can find it described in the zsh documentation in `info zsh 'Parameter Expansion'`:

> `${NAME+WORD}`
> `${NAME:+WORD}`
> If `NAME` is set, or in the second form is non-null, then substitute
> `WORD`; otherwise substitute nothing.

It's harder to find in `info bash 'Parameter Expansion'` but it's the same there. For `sh`, you can check [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (though like in the bash manual, you need to pay attention to the sentence that mentions the effect of omitting the colon in `${parameter:+word}`¹).

The main difference with bash and other Bourne-like shells, is that that `${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}` being unquoted is not subject to split+glob, because in zsh, when you do want IFS-splitting and/or globbing performed upon parameter expansion you have to request it explicitly (`$=var` for splitting, `$~var` for globbing (strictly speaking for the contents of `$var` to be treated as a pattern), `$=~var` for both, which be the equivalent of `$var` in other shells).

It's wrong though as unquoted expansions are still subject to empty removal. In that case though, by accident, it's not going to be a problem, and may be why the author chose to write it `[ ! -z $expansion ]` instead of `[ -n $expansion ]` which wouldn't work.

If `$expansion` is empty (in the case of `${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}` if `$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM` is not set), `[ ! -z $expansion ]` becomes `[ ! -z ]` instead of `[ ! -z '' ]`, so it doesn't test whether the expansion is non empty, but whether `-z` itself is an empty string (which it isn't obviously), so it achieves the right outcome (test whether the variable is set) for the wrong reason.

In bash, that unquoted `${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}` would have been subject to split+glob so that would be even more wrong, but because it can only expand to either the empty string or a literal `x`, the problem would have been only if `$IFS` happened to contain `x`:

```
$ bash -xc 'IFS=y; [ ! -z ${HOME+x} ]; echo "$?"'
+ IFS=y
+ '[' '!' -z x ']'
+ echo 0
0
$ bash -xc 'IFS=x; [ ! -z ${HOME+x} ]; echo "$?"'
+ IFS=x
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ echo 1
1
$ zsh -xc 'IFS=x; [ ! -z ${HOME+x} ]; echo "$?"'
+zsh:1> IFS=x
+zsh:1> [ ! -z x ']'
+zsh:1> echo 0
0
```

The [correct syntax in any POSIX shell](/a/246703) would be:

```
if [ -n "${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}" ]
```

Even works here in the Bourne shell where `[ -n "$var" ]` fails for values of `$var` that are things like `=`, `-gt`... as the expansion can only be `x` or the empty string (so not any of the problematic ones in those ancient implementations of `[`).

Now zsh has more idiomatic ways to check whether a variable is set such as:

```
if (( $+ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM ))
```

Where `$+var` expands to `1` if `$var` is set and `0` otherwise.

Or:

```
if [[ -v ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM ]]
```

À la ksh (also found in bash).

In any case, `[ ! -z "$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM" ]`, itself a convoluted way to write `[ -n "$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM" ]` does something different: if checks whether the variable is non-empty or not regardless of whether it is set or not. The main difference is that it will return false if `$ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM` is set, but to an empty value. Contrary to the `${ZSH_MOTD_CUSTOM+x}` variant, it would also cause an error if the variable was unset and the `nounset` option was enabled.

```
$ zsh -c 'if [ -n "$foo" ]; then echo non-empty; else echo empty; fi'
empty
$ foo= zsh -o nounset -c 'if [ -n "$foo" ]; then echo non-empty; else echo empty; fi'
empty
$ foo= zsh -o nounset -c 'if [ -n "${foo+x}" ]; then echo set; else echo unset; fi'
set
$ zsh -o nounset -c 'if [ -n "$foo" ]; then echo non-empty; else echo empty; fi'
zsh:1: foo: parameter not set
$ zsh -o nounset -c 'if [ -n "${foo+x}" ]; then echo set; else echo unset; fi'
unset
$ zsh -o nounset -c 'if [ -n "${foo-}" ]; then echo non-empty; else echo empty; fi'
empty
```

(in the last one, we use `${foo-}` which expands to the same thing as `$foo` but avoids the effect of `nounset` (aka `set -u`)).

---

<sup>¹ Note that in the Bourne shell where the feature comes from, initially (in Unix 7<sup>th</sup> edition from the late 70s) only the versions without colon were supported, the ones with colons came later [in SysIII](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/index.html#system3).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This isn't due to `test`, but on zsh variable expansion.

The construct `${foo+bar}` will return `bar` if `$foo` is set.

So, for example:

```
zsh% unset foo
zsh% echo ${foo+bar}

zsh% foo=
zsh% echo ${foo+bar}
bar
```